# Is there a copyonwritestack similar to copyonwritearraylist?

Tags: java, multithreading, stack

I have two threads with a global stack variable. Thread1 receives incoming messages and puts into the Stack. Thread 2 checks whether there is any received message/s in the Stack and processes it.

But, i'm receiving exceptions like this when I run my program:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 1

java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Unknown
```

These exceptions didn't arise when i didn't use threads. But, suddenly came up when I converted my program into two threads. Is there a copyonwritestack similar to copyonwritearraylist?

Comment: There's nothing that should prevent you from using a `List` like a stack. You'll need to post code to find the error.

Comment: @Kayaman You're right, though these days, I'd use an ArrayDeque. I have used an ArrayList as a stack, though. It'll perform better than Stack or LinkedList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is probably thrown because the `Stack` implementation you chose is not **thread-safe**.

Try using a concurrent implementation of a Stack such as [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) which implements the [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface.

Also, as stated in the doc:

> This interface [Deque] should be used in preference to the legacy Stack class.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help.

How can i get an element from a specific position from a ConcurrentLinkedDeque ? 


Thanks and regards,

Rajesh.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into this class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help.

How can i get an element from a specific position from a ConcurrentLinkedDeque ? 


Thanks and regards,

Rajesh.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, for message passing, you use Queues, not Stacks. And since this involves threads, something like a BlockingQueue or a ConcurrentLinkedQueue. The reasons for this are so that if the producers and consumers don't run at the same speed, at least with a BlockingQueue, you can guard against messages piling up forever. Queues, in general, protect you from the situation where the producer is ahead of the consumer, and the message at the bottom of the stack never gets popped.